# How to add a flyback diode to protect a relay on another PCB that does not have a flyback diode

Tags: relay, flyback

I have a PCB (SEPARATE PCB) that I want to test by building up a "Test PCB". The test will involve switching the relays. This PCB (SEPARATE PCB) has a few relays on it, however, they do not have any flyback diodes on it.

I am using an Atmega32 to turn on an IRL540 logic MOSFET. I thought by applying a flyback diode across a resistor and an LED on my Test PCB then the voltage spike can be suppressed through my Test PCB instead of the SEPARATE PCB that does not have a flyback diode.

**D3 is a 20V Zener diode**

I am not PWMing the MOSFET, just using it has a switch.

Is this method okay? If not how do I prevent the spike from the SEPARATE PCB using my Test PCB?

**I cannot tamper with the SEPARATE PCB, by adding components to it**

Before:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f145Sv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

After:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC1YN7.png)</sup>

Comment: Is the the same 12V supply on the two boards?

Comment: @KevinWhite not the same 12V supply, however the grounds are common

Comment: Are those 12V on the pcbs provided by the same power supply? D1 is a mid-/high-power LED, right? Other wise 50Ohm is not suitable...

Comment: @SimSon I used the wrong forward current value. I have updated it to 500 ohm now. The 12V source power supplies are different

Comment: 12 V and 500 Ω will give over 20 mA to the LED. While that will work, you may find the LED is excessively bright.

Comment: Be aware that the ATMEGA32 GND(Vss) pin must be connected to M1 source. Currently not shown on OP's schematic.

Comment: Flyback diodes do *not* protect the relay (which doesn't *need* protection), they protect the circuitry switching the relay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is this method okay? If not how do I prevent the spike from the
> SEPARATE PCB using my Test PCB?*

If you can't modify the relay board then you have fewer options: -

- A flyback diode as you have shown providing both 12 volt supplies are linked else...
- A Zener diode (rated at least 3 volts higher than your relay supply voltage) with cathode to M1's drain and anode to 0 volts.
- A snubber (a resistor in series with a capacitor) across M1 drain and 0 volts

Note that R2 likely is too small in value for a standard LED.

Circuit showing zener and snubber options: -

[image]

Put the snubber (or zener) across the MOSFET as close to the MOSFET as you can. The snubber protects the MOSFET so, it should be closest to the MOSFET but, don't worry if it's an inch either way.

A regular parallel diode with the relay (close up) keeps back-emf current local to the relay and, when placed further away, extends the back-emf current loop and can cause EM interference so, it's a compromise in not having that diode directly across the relay coil.

Make sure that if you do opt for the diode to your local positive supply, that power supply should not be too much lower than the relay 12 volts else it'll keep the relay activated when the MOSFET is deactivated. Given all of this, I favour a zener or the snubber.

Watch out for wiring non-idealities that can cause relay or relay load currents to flow into the ATMEGA control and potentially reset it. That is why I suggest a star-point grounding arrangement.

Comment: Will the relay input into my PCB, be inserted after the capacitor or before the resistor?

Comment: Yes, snubber across the MOSFET as close to the MOSFET as you can. The snubber protects the MOSFET so, it should be closest to the MOSFET but, don't worry if it's an inch either way. A regular parallel diode with the relay (close up) keeps back-emf current local to the relay and, when placed further away, extends the back-emf current loop and can cause EM interference so, it's a compromise in not putting a diode across the relay coil.

Comment: Make sure that if you do opt for the diode, your MOSFET power supply should not be too much lower than the relay 12 volts else it'll keep the relay activated when the MOSFET is deactivated. Given all of this, I favour a zener or the snubber.

Comment: @JoeyB I've added the circuit.

Comment: I usually use a ground plane polygon. Is this not a advised as in your last paragraph in your answer?

Comment: @JoeyB when it comes to power supply routing it's a toss-up between full ground plane and star-pointing. Given that I know nothing about what the relays are switching and what other direct loads there may be on your system or, whether that are multiple 0 volt connections to other ground places that might cause surge currents, I have to advise a star-point system based on (a) knowing it won't be as good as a GP system except when the loading currents are medium or greater. Hence, I plumped for star-point as a recommendation.

Comment: You should make it clear in your question that you have made "the following changes" after taking advice from this this or that answer. Reason: someone fresh might look at your revised question and think my answer is telling you what you already knew. They might not be keen on this. Always best to indicate changes once at least one answer is given.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will update the post. Just checking if the revised circuit is okay though?

Comment: Apart from concerns about grounding (previously discussed), it looks fine joey

Comment: If A Zener to gnd turns off faster than diode to V+, Then a 40V TVS would turn off even faster with more peak power but lower average power.  If the load was inductive and also snubbed or clamped. Which improves MTBF from lowering the average contact arc power and thus temperature?    A faster turn-off or slower with a lower Arc voltage.  Can you compute? guess which?

Answer (score 1):

This will work in principle, but:

1: The diode is not to protect the relay, but to protect the switching MOSFET.

2: If the '12V' for the test PCB is lower than the '12V' for the separate PCB, then the relay will turn off very slowly, or may not turn off at all. This is because the flyback diode will allow current to flow from the separate 12 V, through the relay, the diode D2 and *into* the test 12V.

3: If you (accidentally) disconnect the test 12V supply while the relay is energized, then when the MOSFET turns off, there will be clamping action when the hMOSFET turns off, and it may be damaged.

The most rugged solution is to add a (>> 12 V -- say 20 V) zener diode, and a normal diode in series with it, between drain and gate of M1. This will clamp independently of the test 12V supply.

You could totally eliminate the test 12V supply from your system by taking the cathode of D2 and instead of connecting to the test 12V, connect through a 12 V zener (cathode to cathode) to the gate of M1. Now connect the LED + resistor between the GPIO and GND.

[image: added zener + possible new LED connection]

Comment: Is it possible to include a schematic of the Circuits you mentioned to remove any ambiguity when connecting it up?